# How to de-authenticate from Earth Engine API

Tags: python, google-earth-engine-python-api

### Question

I am using the Python API of Google Earth Engine and I authenticated myself a long time ago with :

```py
import ee 
ee.Authenticate()
```

I can now connect myself directly using `ee.Initialize()`

My question is how to revoke this authentification process ?

### Context

I am building a test suits for my librairy.
instead of using ee.Initialize() in the files that requires GEE API I created a function that check if the credential exists in the system (because of course they are unavailable in travis) to use a json private key file if necessary:

```py
def init_ee():
    """Initialize earth engine according to the environment"""
    
    # only do the initialization if the credential are missing
    if not ee.data._credentials:
        
        # if in test env use the private key
        if 'EE_PRIVATE_KEY' in os.environ:
            
            # key need to be decoded in a file
            content = base64.b64decode(os.environ['EE_PRIVATE_KEY']).decode()
            with open('ee_private_key.json', 'w') as f:
                f.write(content)
    
            # connection to the service account
            service_account = 'test-sepal-ui@sepal-ui.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
            credentials = ee.ServiceAccountCredentials(service_account, 'ee_private_key.json')
            ee.Initialize(credentials)
        
        # if in local env use the local user credential
        else:
            ee.Initialize()
            
    return 0
```

I would like to launch my test suit in the same condition as in travis without pushing to github

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credentials are cached in something like `~/.config/earthengine/credentials`

Removing that file should de-authenticate you